# Can a browser render a website and download its content to show without caching or saving anything to the computer?

Tags: cache, browsers, windows, render

Can a browser render a website without caching anything to the computer and just downloading the website ‘live’? I’m not sure if that is how it works, but in other words can a browser show a website without any of the website’s data being written to the computer? I assume it would be held in RAM maybe?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to know this information? Are you trying to find a browser that works like this? Or are you trying to make your website not cached by any browser?

Comment: This is possible generally speaking, but as Patrick and Stephen mentioned, it depends on which parts of the system you have control over and on what result you are trying to achieve. When Patrick writes that he believes this is a "typical X/Y case", he is referring to [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/299116) - please read through that resource and edit your question accordingly to include more details. Thanks!

Comment: I see that this question was closed - editing your question to include more details will also add it to the queue to be considered for re-opening.

Comment: I suspect it stems from the fear that some devs have over theirs css and javascript  being copied.

Comment: [Incognito](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9845881?hl=en#zippy=%2Chow-incognito-mode-works) mode in Chromium browsers won't save cache. If you don't want cache to be written to your disk at all however, you'll need to create a [RAM drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive) and then change the cache and cookies location in your browser settings to use that.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume it would be held in RAM maybe?

Yes, data acquired over the network has to be stored somewhere locally. It can be stored on hard disk for durability, but has at least to be somewhere in memory for usability. For very specific needs (sensitive operations) it can be made to be erased properly from memory immediately after use, or put in special parts of the memory that ensures only specific processes have access to it, and so on. But in your use case, the web, the content is **displayed** anyway at some point. So even if removed from memory, a screenshot just creates it again,

Not sure what REAL problem you are trying to solve (this really seems a typical X/Y case), but trying to think in term of "I am sending data to browser but the browser don't have any copy of it somehow" is not the correct way.